# How do we identify a session in Oracle GV$SESSION view?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-rac

I am trying to understand what is the minimal set of parameters to uniquely identify a session in `GV$SESSION`. I have seen a few online examples there `AUDSID`, `SID`, and `INST_ID` are used, I am trying to understand why?

Answer (score 2):

SID and SERIAL# are enough in V$SESSION for single instance database.

SID, SERIAL#, INST_ID are enough for RAC cluster database in GV$SESSION.

NB: no need to use GV$SESSION if not RAC.

Answer (score 1):

For a given instance, a session is uniquely identified by its `SID` and its `SERIAL#`, as [explained in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-SESSION.html#GUID-28E2DC75-E157-4C0A-94AB-117C205789B9):

> `SID`: Session identifier
>
> `SERIAL#`: Session serial number. Used to uniquely identify a session's objects. Guarantees that session-level commands are applied to the correct session objects if the session ends and another session begins with the same session ID.

You can add `INST_ID` to that if you are running a RAC environment.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pair of values `SID` and `SERIAL#`

Description on both of them in [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2088.htm#REFRN30223) explains why:

SID

- Session identifier

SERIAL#

- Session serial number. Used to uniquely identify a session's objects. Guarantees that session-level commands are applied to the correct session objects if the session ends and another session begins with the same session ID.

Answer (score 1):

GV$session vs  V$session is used on standalone database, an gv$session (g=global) is used mostly on RAC environments.

**AUDSID** is a unique identifier for the session and is used in sys.aud$ , as the SESSIONID column. It is the leading column of the only index on sys.aud$

**INST_ID** column displays the instance number from which the associated V$ view information was obtained

The best way to understand both of them to refer to Oracle documentation and understand what each column do,

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2088.htm#REFRN30223